# Use half of an MUX

Tags: multiplexer, cadence

Can someone give me the schematics of this half 74153 mux?

[image: A half 74153 mux]

Comment: Have you looked for the datasheet?  74LS153 or 74HC153 (or similar variations) will have the same logic diagram.

Comment: yes but I can't find the half version of it

Comment: The 74153 is a dual 4 input mux - the datasheet shows the full logic diagram with the two mux's.  Your schematic just uses one of the two mux's in the chip.  The other mux may be used elsewhere in the circuit.

Comment: See that A, B are shared internally. https://i.stack.imgur.com/62CeV.png